# Parsing Redis MONITOR messages

Tags: python, parsing, redis

I'm trying to build a bridge between a Redis server and MQTT, so that when the Redis database is updated, these updates are dispatched via MQTT to clients.

For this a client (only one, the bridge) connects to the Redis database and starts to monitor it.

My issue is with parsing the commands, more specifically the arguments contained with it, which is a whitespace-separated list of stings.

For example, when I store the following hash in Redis

```
data = {
  "key-3-1-json": "value-1",
  "key-3-2-json": 'this "this is \'quoted\' text"',
}
print r18.hmset("test-hash", {
  "key-1": "value-1",
  "key-2": 'this "this is \'quoted\' text"',
  "key-3": json.dumps(data),
})
```

the client recieves the following

`1549578825.1 0 HMSET test-hash "key-3" "{\"key-3-1-json\": \"value-1\", \"key-3-2-json\": \"this \\\"this is 'quoted' text\\\"\"}" "key-2" "this \"this is 'quoted' text\"" "key-1" "value-1"`

As you can see I'm already parsing the timestamp, database id, command and key, but the last part, I don't know how to create a list of strings from it.

This message would then be sent over MQTT as

`mqtt.publish("redis/mon/0/HMSET/test-hash", json.dumps(args))`

where `args` would be

```
[
  "key-3",
  "{\"key-3-1-json\": \"value-1\", \"key-3-2-json\": \"this \\\"this is 'quoted' text\\\"\"}",
  "key-2",
  "this \"this is 'quoted' text\"",
  "key-1",
  "value-1"
]
```

which would probably be the most complex case, since usually the args would be one single string, in the case where `r18.set` would have been used instead of `r18.hmset`.

---

I think there must be some built-in module in Python which could to this as it is like parsing a command line string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `subprocess` module's documentation states that `subprocess.Popen()` makes use of `shlex.split()` ([shlex: Simple lexical analysis](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html))

Calling `shlex.split(args_str)` effectively converts the arguments string into the desired list of substrings.